# “Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context.”

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't run the code and I don't get what's wrong with it.

```
function onOpen(a) {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi() // ..
}
```

[image: How it looks like]

Error:

> Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context. (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: This is the image          https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbWeY.jpg

Comment: This works in a Spreadsheet:


    `function onOpen(e) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello');
    }`

This works in a Document:

    `function onOpen(e) {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Hello');
    }`

Comment: I would move the onOpen(e) function definition out of the onInstall(e) function definition.

Comment: Thx Cooper! I fixed that and I have another problem. Can you help me?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478794/what-did-i-do-wrong-on-this-script-it-says-cannot-find-function-createmenu-in

Comment: @Cooper - perhaps add your comment as an answer and so OP can accept and close this question?

Answer (score 4):

This works in a Spreadsheet: `function onOpen(e) { SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello')}`

This works in a Document: `function onOpen(e) { DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Hello'); }`

I would move the onOpen(e) function definition out of the onInstall(e) function definition.