# What did I do wrong on this script? It says "Cannot find function createMenu in object Spreadsheet."

Tags: google-apps-script

What did I do wrong?

```
function onInstall() {
    onOpen();
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .createMenu('Sentrix Messaging')
        .addItem('Index', 'new mail')
        .addItem('Compose', 'Write mail')
        .addToUi();
    Browser.msgBox('Welcome to Sentrix Email');
    ShowSidebar();
}

function showSidebar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Inbox")
        .evaluate()
        .setTitle("Email");
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
}
```

It says

> Cannot find function createMenu in object Spreadsheet

Comment: Write your code and don't put it into an image.

Comment: Here   DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Sentrix Email')
      .addItem('Inbox', 'new mail')
      .addItem('Compose', 'Write mail')
      .addToUi();

Comment: The problem is it says cannot find function create menu

Comment: It should be `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake with brackets.

```
function onInstall() {
    onOpen();
}
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .createMenu('Sentrix Messaging')
        .addItem('Index', 'new mail')
        .addItem('Compose', 'Write mail')
        .addToUi();
    Browser.msgBox('Welcome to Sentrix Email');
    ShowSidebar();
}

function showSidebar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Inbox")
        .evaluate()
        .setTitle("Email");
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```